# Application validation was skipped - when archiving an app for submission

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning

I am trying to archive my iPad app for submission (with a distribution provisioning profile) but I am getting this warning:

> 2012-01-17 15:48:12.739 Validation[576:f07] Could not find application
>   with identifier “com.apple.itunes.connect.ApplicationLoader” (err =
>   -10814) warning: Application validation was skipped.

Any ideas? I am going nuts and can't find any solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try looking under the "Build Settings" tab for your project. Under "Build options" and "Code signing" make sure that all of the correct values are selected that is that you have "Yes" for validating release builds and also set the correct Code signing identities. I have never had this problem, but I hope this helps a little.

Answer (score 0):

Also, remember that there is a difference between the project settings and the target settings. I had to go into the target settings to fix this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your Application Loader (one of the Xcode utilities) may be missing or corrupt.  Reinstall Application Loader, and then you can properly archive your app.